# First Persistent example from Yesod book won't compile -- can't find persist

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm trying to run the Persistent examples in the Yesod book (Chapter 10). I entered the initial example in a .hs file, created a cabal file, and tried to compile. The compiler complains it can't find "persist". I assume the function persist has moved to a new package (which I haven't included) or has been deprecated, but I don't know which and hoogle hasn't shed any light on the issue. Any help would be much appreciated.  Perhaps I should revert to the version of Yesod that the book is based on. Which yesod-platform should I install for that?  Thanks, Tim

Here is the error message:

```
perry$ cabal install
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring chapter10-0.1.0.0...
Building chapter10-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'chapter10' for chapter10-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ex1.hs, dist/build/chapter10/chapter10-tmp/Main.o )

ex1.hs:8:55: Not in scope: `persist'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
chapter10-0.1.0.0 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

Here is my chapter10.cabal file:

```
-- Initial chapter10.cabal generated by cabal init.  For further 
-- documentation, see http://haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/
name:                chapter10
version:             0.1.0.0
license-file:        LICENSE
cabal-version:       >=1.8
build-type:          Simple

executable chapter10
  main-is:             ex1.hs
  -- other-modules:       
  build-depends:       base ==4.5.*
                       , yesod-platform
                       , yesod
                       , persistent-sqlite
                       , transformers
                       , persistent-template
                       , persistent
```

Here is my ex1.hs file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies, OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Database.Persist
import Database.Persist.Sqlite
import Database.Persist.TH
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (liftIO)

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persist|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
BlogPost
    title String
    authorId PersonId
    deriving Show
|]

main :: IO ()
main = withSqliteConn ":memory:" $ runSqlConn $ do
    runMigration migrateAll

    johnId <- insert $ Person "John Doe" $ Just 35
    janeId <- insert $ Person "Jane Doe" Nothing

    insert $ BlogPost "My fr1st p0st" johnId
    insert $ BlogPost "One more for good measure" johnId

    oneJohnPost <- selectList [BlogPostAuthorId ==. johnId] [LimitTo 1]
    liftIO $ print (oneJohnPost :: [Entity BlogPost])

    john <- get johnId
    liftIO $ print (john :: Maybe Person)

    delete janeId
    deleteWhere [BlogPostAuthorId ==. johnId]
```

Here are the versions of my yesod and persistent packages:

```
perry$ ghc-pkg list| grep -i -e yesod -e persist
    persistent-1.2.0.1
    persistent-sqlite-1.2.0
    persistent-template-1.2.0.1
    yesod-1.2.1
    yesod-auth-1.2.0.1
    yesod-core-1.2.2
    yesod-form-1.3.0
    yesod-persistent-1.2.1
    yesod-platform-1.2.1
    yesod-routes-1.2.0.1
    yesod-static-1.2.0
    yesod-test-1.2.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [some older documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/persistent-template/1.1.3.1/doc/html/Database-Persist-TH.html#v:persist), `persist` was deprecated. It appears to have been removed in version 1.2.0.

> `persist :: QuasiQuoter`
>
> Deprecated: Please use `persistUpperCase` instead.

Comment: Ah...I never thought to check the older documentation. I just looked at 1.2.0.0 and 1.2.0.1. Thanks for thinking for me!